# What does the error "TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'vectorize' and 'vectorize'" mean?

Tags: python, numpy

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 95, in <module>
    if mPLocX > mPLocY:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'vectorize' and 'vectorize'
```

From this program:

```
import numpy as np
#For the array
import random as ran
#For random starting positions
import math
#To find the difference in position

field = np.array([
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
])

my = ran.randint(0, 5)
  #Monster Y 
mx = ran.randint(0, 5)
  #Monster X
py = ran.randint(0, 5)
  #Player Y
px = ran.randint(0, 5)
  #Player X

if my != py and mx != my:
 field[my, mx] = 1
 field[py, px] = 2
else:
 my = ran.randint(0, 5)
  #Monster Y 
 mx = ran.randint(0, 5)
  #Monster X
 py = ran.randint(0, 5)
  #Player Y
 px = ran.randint(0, 5)
  #Player X
 field[my, mx] = 1
 field[py, px] = 2
  
mPLocY = 0
#Monster Player Location Y
mPLocX = 0
#Monster Player Location X
turn = 0

for i in range(20):
 turn += 1
 trueTurn = turn % 2
 if trueTurn == 1:
  print ("Player's Turn")
 else:
  print ("Monster's turn")
   
 print("Monster is at:" + str(mx) + ", " + str(my))
 print("Player is at " + str(px) + ", " + str(py))
 pLoc = np.where(field == 2)
#pLoc = Player Location (declared in loop)
 mLoc = np.where(field == 1)
#mLoc = Monster Location (declared in loop)
 (my, mx) = mLoc
 if turn == 0:
  mPLocX = math.fabs(mx - px)
  #Monster Player Location X (declared out of loop)
  mPLocY = math.fabs(my - py)
  #Monster Player Location Y (declared out of loop)
 else:
  mPLocX = np.vectorize(math.fabs(mx - px))
  #Monster Player Location X (declared out of loop)
  mPLocY = np.vectorize(math.fabs(my - py))
  #Monster Player Location Y (declared out of loop)
 if trueTurn == 1:
  drctn = input("Input a direction (wasd): ")
#drctn means Direction
  if drctn == "w":
   field[py, px] = 0
   py = py + 1
   field[py, px] = 2
  elif drctn == "s":
   field[py, px] = 0
   py = py - 1
   field[py, px] = 2
  elif drctn == "a":
   field[py, px] = 0
   px = px - 1
   field[py, px] = 2
  elif drctn == "d":
   field[py, px] = 0
   px = px + 1
   field[py, px] = 2
  else:
   print("Error!")
    
 else:
  if mPLocX > mPLocY:
   if mx > px:
    field[my, mx] = 0
    mx = mx - 1
    field[my, mx] = 2
   else:
    field[my, mx] = 0
    mx = mx + 1
    field[my, mx] = 2
     
  else:
   if my > py:
    field[my, mx] = 0
    py = py - 1
    field[my, mx] = 2
   else:
    field[my, mx] = 0
    py = py - 1
    field[my, mx] = 2
```

The first time the loop code goes, there are no errors. Come second iteration, `mx` and `my` become shapes. The error originates at lines 62–71.

I tried just getting rid of the `vectorize`, but that doesn't work. I tried using `astype` on all of the separate variables, but that did not work. It only works with the `if`/`else` thing, because on the first loop, they are not shapes.

Comment: Note that `np.vectorize` doesn't actually vectorize anything https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html says _"The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."_

Comment: The variables start off as integers `mPLocY = 0`, but then later they can become a different type `mPLocY = np.vectorize(math.fabs(my - py))`.  You need to decide what type those variables should be, and make sure they stay that way.

Comment: `mPLocX` produced by `np.vectorize` is a function.  You can't do math, including `>` on functions.  That's for comparing numbers and arrays of numbers.  Also, `math.fabs(mx - px)` is a number, the result of applying `math.fabs` to a number.  It isn't appropriate input to `np.vectorize`. I'm not sure if you've just skipped reading the `np.vectorize` docs, or if you are missing some background that will help you understand those docs.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you wrote

> ```
> mPLocX = np.vectorize(math.fabs(mx - px))
> mPLocY = np.vectorize(math.fabs(my - py))
> ```

which makes `mPLocX` and `mPLocY` instances of `np.vectorize` (whether they make sense or not is another topic).

Then you wrote

> ```
> if mPLocX > mPLocY:
> ```

which raises the exception you are seeing, because the `>` operator is not supported between instances of `np.vectorize`.

It seems you intended to take the element-wise absolute value of an array that is the element-wise difference between two other arrays (whether `mx` and `px` etc. are actually arrays or just single numbers is yet another topic).

NumPy can already do the element-wise calculations out-of-the box. You don't need to use `np.vectorize`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> b = np.array([2, 4, 1])
>>> a - b
array([-1, -2,  2])
>>> np.abs(a - b)
array([1, 2, 2])
```